# dplyr joining two datasets together with conditions

Tags: r

I have two datasets I am trying to join together.

`df1` looks like:

```
        ID     date_f
1     4281 2019-02-21
2  1108827 2004-03-15
3     6201 2012-02-27
4   310158 2010-03-01
5   711065 2016-02-25
6   314808 2003-03-11
7    45012 2004-05-12
8   745732 2014-11-21
9  1458891 2013-10-28
10  316206 2007-05-30
```

Whereas `df2` looks like:

```
     ID       date year
1  6201 1999-12-31 1999
2  6201 2000-12-31 2000
3  6201 2001-12-31 2001
4  6201 2002-12-31 2002
5  6201 2003-12-31 2003
6  6201 2004-12-31 2004
7  6201 2017-12-31 2017
8  6201 2005-12-31 2005
9  6201 2006-12-31 2006
10 6201 2007-12-31 2007
11 6201 2008-12-31 2008
12 6201 2009-12-31 2009
13 6201 2010-12-31 2010
14 6201 2011-12-31 2011
15 6201 2012-12-31 2012
16 6201 2013-12-31 2013
17 6201 2014-12-31 2014
18 6201 2015-12-31 2015
19 6201 2016-12-31 2016
20 6201 2018-12-31 2018
```

I am trying to join them (the dates do not match):

Method:

Join by `ID` and when `date < date_f`

Expected Output (Using the first 5 observations from `df1`:

```
        ID     date_f     date     year
1     4281 2019-02-21  2018-12-31  2018
2  1108827 2004-03-15  2003-12-31  2003
3     6201 2012-02-27  2011-12-31  2011
4   310158 2010-03-01  2009-12-31  2009
5   711065 2016-02-25  2015-03-31  2014
```

For example row 2 above has a `date_f` in `df1` of `2004-03-15` one way would be to merge it with the `year()` and it would get joined with `2004-12-31` - however this date is after the date in `df1`. So I am trying to merge it with the previous date which is `2003-12-31`.

The final row 5 would have been joined with `2016-03-31` however the `date_f` is less than this date. `2016-02-25` in `date_f` < `2016-03-31` in `date`.

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(4281L, 1108827L, 6201L, 310158L, 711065L, 
314808L, 45012L, 745732L, 1458891L, 316206L), date_f = c("2019-02-21", 
"2004-03-15", "2012-02-27", "2010-03-01", "2016-02-25", "2003-03-11", 
"2004-05-12", "2014-11-21", "2013-10-28", "2007-05-30")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002511ef0>, class = "data.frame")
```

Data 2

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 
6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 
6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 6201L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 
314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 
314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 
314808L, 314808L, 314808L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 
45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 
45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 45012L, 316206L, 
316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 
316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 316206L, 
316206L, 316206L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 
310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 
310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 310158L, 
310158L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 
745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 
745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 745732L, 
745732L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 
1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 
1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 1458891L, 
4281L, 4281L, 4281L, 4281L, 4281L, 4281L, 4281L, 711065L, 711065L, 
711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 
711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 711065L, 
711065L, 711065L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 
1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 
1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L, 1108827L), 
    date = c("1999-12-31", "2000-12-31", "2001-12-31", "2002-12-31", 
    "2003-12-31", "2004-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2005-12-31", "2006-12-31", 
    "2007-12-31", "2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", 
    "2012-12-31", "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", 
    "2018-12-31", "1999-12-31", "2000-12-31", "2001-12-31", "2002-12-31", 
    "2003-12-31", "2004-12-31", "2005-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2007-12-31", 
    "2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", "2012-12-31", 
    "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
    "2018-12-31", "1999-12-31", "2000-12-31", "2001-12-31", "2002-12-31", 
    "2003-12-31", "2004-12-31", "2005-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2007-12-31", 
    "2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", "2012-12-31", 
    "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
    "2018-12-31", "1999-12-31", "2000-12-31", "2001-12-31", "2002-12-31", 
    "2003-12-31", "2004-12-31", "2005-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2007-12-31", 
    "2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", "2012-12-31", 
    "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "1999-12-31", "2000-12-31", 
    "2001-12-31", "2002-12-31", "2003-12-31", "2004-12-31", "2005-12-31", 
    "2006-12-31", "2007-12-31", "2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", 
    "2011-12-31", "2012-12-31", "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", 
    "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "1999-01-31", "2000-01-31", 
    "2001-01-31", "2002-01-31", "2003-01-31", "2004-01-31", "2005-01-31", 
    "2006-01-31", "2007-01-31", "2008-01-31", "2009-01-31", "2010-01-31", 
    "2011-01-31", "2012-01-31", "2013-01-31", "2014-01-31", "2015-01-31", 
    "2016-01-31", "2017-01-31", "2018-01-31", "2019-01-31", "1999-12-31", 
    "2000-12-31", "2001-12-31", "2002-12-31", "2003-12-31", "2004-12-31", 
    "2005-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2007-12-31", "2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", 
    "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", "2012-12-31", "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", 
    "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2012-12-31", 
    "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
    "2018-12-31", "1999-03-31", "2000-03-31", "2001-03-31", "2002-03-31", 
    "2003-03-31", "2004-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2006-03-31", "2007-03-31", 
    "2008-03-31", "2009-03-31", "2010-03-31", "2011-03-31", "2012-03-31", 
    "2013-03-31", "2014-03-31", "2015-03-31", "2016-03-31", "2001-12-31", 
    "2002-12-31", "2003-12-31", "2004-12-31", "2005-12-31", "2006-12-31", 
    "2007-12-31", "2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", 
    "2012-12-31", "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", 
    "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31"), year = c(1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
    2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2017L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2018L, 1999L, 
    2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
    2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
    2018L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
    2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
    2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
    2014L, 2015L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
    2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
    2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
    2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
    2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1999L, 2000L, 
    2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
    2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1998L, 1999L, 
    2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
    2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2001L, 2002L, 
    2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
    2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-181L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002511ef0>, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Sure I Will write something up now!

Comment: I have added an expected output and change the data since it was breaking for me.

Comment: Do you need `library(data.table);setDT(df2)[df1, on = .(ID, date < date_f)]`

Comment: The `date_f` column in `df1` corresponds to some report date, whereas the `date` column in `df2` corresponds to some financial data which did not exist when the report came out which is why I want to join the data together by using the last available financial data which must be before the report date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option is with rolling joins from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, date_f := date][df1, on = .(ID, date_f), roll = Inf]
#       ID       date year     date_f
#1:    4281 2018-12-31 2018 2019-02-21
#2: 1108827 2003-12-31 2003 2004-03-15
#3:    6201 2011-12-31 2011 2012-02-27
#4:  310158 2009-12-31 2009 2010-03-01
#5:  711065 2015-03-31 2014 2016-02-25
#6:  314808 2002-12-31 2002 2003-03-11
#7:   45012 2003-12-31 2003 2004-05-12
#8:  745732 2014-01-31 2013 2014-11-21
#9: 1458891 2012-12-31 2012 2013-10-28
#10: 316206 2006-12-31 2006 2007-05-30
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the 'date/date_f' columns to be `Date` class

Comment: Thanks! It Works (along with the other solution). I have another way I wish to merge these two data sets also (kind of the "other-way around"). Previously I wanted to take the "report" and use the last available financial information. I would also like to take this report and "predict" the financial in `t+1` based on some condition. I Will open a new question as I need to explain myself a Little more clear! Thanks again!

Comment: I asked a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537032/joining-data-by-date-based-on-time-period-condition

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below will give you what you need.

```
data <- df2 %>% 
  inner_join(df1, by="ID") %>%
  filter(date < date_f) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(maxDate = max(date)) %>%
  inner_join(df1, by="ID")
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets the desired result I was hoping for :)