# joining data by date based on time period condition

Tags: r

(This is a follow on question to the one originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535021/dplyr-joining-two-datasets-together-with-conditions).

My original problem has been solved however I would like to merge these two data sets in a slightly different way also.

`df1` is some sort of "financial report" data and `df2` is some sort of "end of year financial data". Previously I wanted to link the financial report data up to the last available financial data.

Now I would like to "forecast" the financial data (`df2`) using the data in the financial report (`df1`). That is link the data by `ID` and `date_f` and `date`.

I would like to impose the following condition:

Join if;

`date` (`t+1`) from `df2` > `date_f` (`t`) from `df1` and the difference must be more than 6 months,

otherwise;

take `date` at `t+2`. (That is, if the `date` (`t+1`) is less than 6 months after `date_f` (`t`) then use the `date` at (`t+2`).

Essentially I want to use the financial report data `df1` to forecast data in `df2` but the information in `df1` is not useful for forecasting 1 week into the future, therefore I would prefer to forecast the following years data.

The data looks like the following;

df1:

```
        ID     date_f
1  1047699 2014-03-03
2   858339 2007-03-01
3  1002910 2009-12-22
4   277135 2011-02-18
5   753308 2004-03-09
6  1018840 2008-02-26
7  1510295 2011-10-21
8     3133 2014-02-27
9  1467858 2010-02-26
10  865436 2004-11-05
```

df2:

```
    ID       date year
1 3133 1999-12-31 1999
2 3133 2000-12-31 2000
3 3133 2001-12-31 2001
4 3133 2002-12-31 2002
5 3133 2003-12-31 2003
6 3133 2004-12-31 2004
```

Expected output using the first 5 rows of `df1`:

```
        ID     date_f   date        year
1  1047699 2014-03-03 
2   858339 2007-03-01   2007-12-31  2007
3  1002910 2009-12-22   2010-12-31  2010 *
4   277135 2011-02-18   2011-12-31  2011
5   753308 2004-03-09   2004-12-31  2004
```

- Here the `date` should be `2009-12-31` which is in `df2` and it is still > `date_f` (by 1 week) however the condition I would like to impose is that "it must be > `date_f` and the `date` be more than 6 months into the future (or 180 days). So here this observation fails on the second condition (since its just 1 week difference) so I would like to "forecast" the next years date which is `2010-12-31`.

data1

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1047699L, 858339L, 1002910L, 277135L, 753308L, 
1018840L, 1510295L, 3133L, 1467858L, 865436L), date_f = structure(c(16132, 
13573, 14600, 15023, 12486, 13935, 15268, 16128, 14666, 12727
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002511ef0>, class = "data.frame")
```

data2

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(3133L, 3133L, 3133L, 3133L, 3133L, 3133L, 
3133L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 
753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 
753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 753308L, 
1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 
1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 
1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 1467858L, 277135L, 
277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 
277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 
277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 277135L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 
1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 
1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 
1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 1002910L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 
858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 
858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 
858339L, 858339L, 858339L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 
865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 
865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 865436L, 
1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 
1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 
1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 1018840L, 
1047699L, 1047699L, 1047699L, 1047699L, 1047699L, 1047699L, 1047699L, 
1047699L, 1047699L, 1047699L, 1047699L, 1510295L, 1510295L, 1510295L, 
1510295L, 1510295L, 1510295L, 1510295L, 1510295L, 1510295L, 1510295L
), date = structure(c(10956, 11322, 11687, 12052, 12417, 12783, 
13148, 10956, 11322, 11687, 12052, 12417, 12783, 13148, 13513, 
13878, 14244, 14609, 14974, 15339, 15705, 16070, 16435, 16800, 
17166, 17531, 17896, 10956, 11322, 11687, 12052, 12417, 12783, 
13148, 13513, 13878, 14244, 14609, 14974, 15339, 15705, 16070, 
16435, 16800, 17166, 17531, 17896, 10956, 11322, 11687, 12052, 
12417, 12783, 13148, 13513, 13878, 14244, 14609, 14974, 15339, 
15705, 16070, 16435, 16800, 17166, 17531, 17896, 10956, 11322, 
11687, 12052, 12417, 12783, 13148, 13513, 13878, 17166, 14244, 
14609, 14974, 15339, 15705, 16070, 16435, 16800, 17531, 17896, 
10956, 11322, 11687, 12052, 12417, 12783, 13148, 13513, 13878, 
14244, 14609, 14974, 15339, 15705, 16070, 16435, 16800, 17166, 
17531, 17896, 10864, 11230, 11595, 11960, 12325, 12691, 13056, 
13421, 13786, 14152, 14517, 14882, 15247, 15613, 15978, 16343, 
16708, 17074, 10622, 10987, 11353, 11718, 12083, 12448, 12814, 
13179, 13544, 13909, 14275, 14640, 15005, 15370, 15736, 16101, 
16466, 16831, 17197, 17562, 17927, 10956, 11322, 11687, 12052, 
12417, 12783, 13148, 13513, 13878, 14244, 14609, 14609, 14974, 
15339, 15705, 16070, 16435, 16800, 17166, 17531, 17896), class = "Date"), 
    year = c(1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
    1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
    2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 
    2017L, 2018L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
    2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
    2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
    2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
    2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2016L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2017L, 2018L, 1999L, 
    2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
    2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
    2018L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
    2016L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
    2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
    2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
    2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-167L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002511ef0>, class = "data.frame")
```

#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solved my issue:

```
df1$start_date <- df1$date_f + 183
df1$end_date <- df1$date_f + 540

library(fuzzyjoin)
yy <- fuzzy_left_join(
  df1, df2,
  by = c(
    "ID" = "ID",
    "start_date" = "date",
    "end_date" = "date"
  ),
  match_fun = list(`==`, `<`, `>=`)
)
```

If anybody sees that I might of failed in my logic please correct me!

If a financial report is released in March and the financial information is released in July, I want to ignore this join. Hence the `start_date <- df1$date_f + 183`. I also set the upper bound to be 1.5 years (540 days) from the release of the financial report. Therefore the following years report Will align correctly with the correct financial information.

A sample of an output:

```
     ID.x     date_f    start_date end_date   ID.y      date     fyear
1  1006835  2008-09-30 2009-04-01 2010-03-24      NA       <NA>    NA
2  1510295  2009-10-19 2010-04-20 2011-04-12 1510295 2010-12-31  2010
3  1506307  2016-02-08 2016-08-09 2017-08-01 1506307 2016-12-31  2016
4   814453  2005-03-15 2005-09-14 2006-09-06  814453 2005-12-31  2005
5   832988  2003-06-19 2003-12-19 2004-12-10  832988 2004-01-31  2003
6  1275283  2007-02-26 2007-08-28 2008-08-19 1275283 2007-12-31  2007
7   858470  2004-03-15 2004-09-14 2005-09-06  858470 2004-12-31  2004
8   885639  2005-03-14 2005-09-13 2006-09-05  885639 2006-01-31  2005
9   732718  2014-04-02 2014-10-02 2015-09-24      NA       <NA>    NA
10 1385157  2009-03-02 2009-09-01 2010-08-24 1385157 2009-09-30  2009
```

I.e. the `ID.x` = `1510295` has a `date.f` = `2009-10-19` and joining by `year` would give me probably the financial information at `2009-12-31` which is only 2 months after the report… (which isn`t very useful to me)

I create the bounds of `start_date` = `2010-04-20` and `end_date` = `2011-04-12`. Where the `start_date` is now greater than the `2009` end of year financial information `2009-12-31`.

Using `fuzzyjoin` to match the `date` from `df2` to the bounds in `df1` I (think) I am able to join them.

`###############################################################################`

If somebody has a `data.table` version, that would be great as this method has memory issues.

```
setDT(df2)[df1, on = .(ID, date > start_date, date <= end_date)]
```

Doesn`t work as expected...